# Why react-dom/server 18.2.0 does not contains renderToReadableStream?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

i use node.js 18.16.0 and react@18.2.0 and react-dom@18.2.0

Here is code example of issue:

```js
import { renderToString, renderToReadableStream } from "react-dom/server";

console.log({ renderToString, renderToReadableStream });
```

Here an error that i receive:

```bash
file:///Users/user/Projects/node-fetch-api-server/test.mjs:1
import { renderToString, renderToReadableStream } from "react-dom/server";
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Named export 'renderToReadableStream' not found. The requested module 'react-dom/server' is a CommonJS module, which may not support all module.exports as named exports.
CommonJS modules can always be imported via the default export, for example using:

import pkg from 'react-dom/server';
const { renderToString, renderToReadableStream } = pkg;

    at ModuleJob._instantiate (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:124:21)
    at async ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:190:5)
```

But when i import only renderToString it working properly.

How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue when importing `react-dom` from inside a worker.
Node incorrectly resolved the `"main"` field of the `react-dom/packaje.json` in my case. It's supposed to resolve to `react-dom/server.browser.js` when referenced from a worker, but it didn't work for me, so I imported the correct bundle directly:

```
import { renderToReadableStream } from 'react-dom/server.browser'; // <- added .browser explicitly
```

Keep in mind, that you should avoid importing renderers from different bundle targets, i.e., this can lead to some nasty bugs:

```
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server';
import { renderToReadableStream } from 'react-dom/server.browser'; // oops! different bundle
```